# How to get full access to uber scopes (Scope.PROFILE, Scope.ALL_TRIPS, Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS)?

Tags: uber-api, scopes

We applied for the Scope:- Scope.PROFILE, Scope.ALL_TRIPS, Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS, but now we’ve lost them due to policy changes uber. We have been trying to resolve this using the following information which was available on the developer site but there was no luck as we couldn’t locate "Request full access" button on the developer dashboard anywhere.
Please suggest how to get full access to scopes.

Comment: I have the same issue, were you able to get access to scope(s)?

Comment: Do you have any news?